# mod_perl not active on Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)

Tags: apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, perl

I am using OTRS on a RedHat 6.5 with apache2 and mod_perl2.
One of my servers (Sandbox environment) has the following (yum info feedback):

```
Installed Packages
Name        : httpd
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.2.15
Release     : 39.el6

Name        : mod_perl
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.0.4
Release     : 11.el6_5
```

We noticed a performance difference with the Development server. So I placed the following script in the same directory as my index.pl to see if mod_perl was being used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "Server's environment\n";
foreach ( keys %ENV ) {
print "$_\t$ENV{$_}\n";
}
```

Sandbox is missing two lines in the 'environment' part of the output compared to Dev:

MOD_PERL_API_VERSION    2

MOD_PERL    mod_perl/2.0.4

So I'm pretty sure mod_perl isn't being used. But as far as I can tell everything is configured:

1) /etc/httpd/conf.d/perl.conf contains the line:
    LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so

2) /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf contains an Include:
    Include conf.d/*.conf

3) this is the default .conf from OTRS but I can't find a mistake:

```
# Setup environment and preload modules
Perlrequire /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-perl-startup.pl

# Reload Perl modules when changed on disk
PerlModule Apache2::Reload
PerlInitHandler Apache2::Reload

# general mod_perl2 options
<Location /otrs>
#        ErrorDocument 403 /otrs/customer.pl
    ErrorDocument 403 /otrs/index.pl
    SetHandler  perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
    Options +ExecCGI
    PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
    PerlOptions +SetupEnv

    <IfModule mod_version.c>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_version.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</Location>

# mod_perl2 options for GenericInterface
<Location /otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl>
    PerlOptions -ParseHeaders
</Location>

</IfModule>
```

And yet the module is loaded:

```
[user@server httpd]$ httpd -M | grep perl
Syntax OK
perl_module (shared)
[user@server httpd]$ httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
core.c
prefork.c
http_core.c
mod_so.c
```

Anyone who can spot a mistake or who has additional steps to troubleshoot why mod_perl isn't being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone ends up here after googling:it has something to do with the line 16 in the default zzz_otrs.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_version.c>
```

as a test I changed it to

```
<IfModule core.c>
```

And then everything works as you would expect it. This is obviously a dirty workaround, if mod_perl is not installed properly this will cause apache to crash. If I find a better (more general) solution than this I will update.